# How do you convert IBM DB2's recursive increment to MySQL version?

Tags: mysql, db2, cte

DB2 Queries:

```
    WITH
    TABLE1 (YEAR_END) as( VALUES
    (2011))
    ,
    TABLE2
    (YEAR_END) AS ( VALUES(2011))
    ,
    TABLE3 (YEARS) AS ( SELECT 0+2008 FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2 
    union all
    select YEARS+1 from TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2, TABLE3 T3
    WHERE  YEARS < 2011
    )

select YEARS from TABLE3
```

---

### Result:

2008
2009
2010
2011

how to change above DB2 statement to Mysql statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive SQL Constructs of this nature do not exist in MySQL.

I know something like ths can be done in SQL Server 2005.

The only WITH operator in MySQL is the [WITH ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) modifier clause in GROUP BY functions.